# How can I find out when Visual Studio theme color changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-extensions

I develop the Visual Studio package with a tool window. The UI of the tool window is based on WPF.
In my user control I want to use current Visual Studio theme colors corresponding to the VS design.

Therefore my question is how I can find out that Visual Studio theme color has been changed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found another way to do it. I can use visual studio theme colors resources from xaml directly. 
For example:

```
Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsfx:VsBrushes.ToolWindowBackgroundKey}}"
```

where vsfx is

```
xmlns:vsfx="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0"
```

This approach solved this problem!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect the theme change event itself, you can make use of the [`VSColorTheme.ThemeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.platformui.vscolortheme.themechanged.aspx) static event.