# Programmatically change Visual Studio options C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio plugin that has a code editor window, the code in this window shows colored to the user. I'm using this project http://colorizeoutput.codeplex.com/ as my base to create options inside the visual studio to manage the colors the code editor should display:

[image]

In the code editor, the result looks like this:

[image]

The problem is, the default colors for these tokens do not show well on the Dark theme:

[image]

I've found how to track the event when visual studio theme changes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231186/how-can-i-find-out-when-visual-studio-theme-color-changes), and how to [find out what what visual studio theme was selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920572/how-to-get-current-used-color-theme-of-visual-studio2012) when that occurs, (I´ve also found out how to figure what version of visual studio is currently running, to open the correct registry key in the previous step) the only problem I have is how to programmaticly set the value of one of those options to what I want, for example, how do I set the "Item foreground" color for the XXXX Keyword with code?

Comment: If you're using the registry, you're doing it wrong.  Visual Studio exposes an API for programmatic access.  See [Visual Studio SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx) and [Extend the Visual Studio IDE](http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/explore/explore-vside-vsi)

Comment: Those links do explain how to create the ClassificationType/Format and Classifier, which is what I'm using to create those options you see in the first image, but what I want to do is modify the values of those afterwards, when the visual studio theme changes and the Editor window is already running.

Comment: This blog post by SLaks looks like about 85% of what you need: http://blog.slaks.net/2014-09-04/getting-started-with-visual-studio-themes/  But I don't know how to get ahold of that ResourceDictionary in order to update it.  If you can find that `ResourceSynchronizer` class he mentions, and see where its theme data is coming from, you'll know where your changes have to get pushed.